# Get name from NameSyntax rather than digging IdentifierNameSyntax or QualifiedNameSyntax

Tags: roslyn

after a var `ns = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>();`
how can I easily get the (qualified) name of the namespace ?

**ns.Name.ToFullString()** would be perfect for me. But it returns the trivia too.

Is there no (shortcut) method on NameSyntax to get the name or the qualified name ?

```
qualifiedname("foo") => foo  
qualifiedname("foo.fee") => foo.fee  
name("foo") => foo  
name("foo.fee") => fee
```

Do i really need to test separately if I get a QualifiedNameSyntax rather than a IdentifierNameSyntax ?

How do you get the (full) name in case of a QualifiedNameSyntax ?
I see there are a Left and Right tokens and I could probably query Name.Left.Identifier but then what to choose Text? Value? ValueText?

What if there are more than 2 levels ?

Comment: What about nested `namespace` blocks?

Comment: I don't understand your remark. Could you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: How do you want to handle `namespace A { namespace B {}}`?

Comment: this results in 2 nested NamespaceDeclarationSyntax, doesn't it ?

Comment: Or maybe the inner will return as a QualifiedNameSyntax ?